Who is the manufacturer of this storm door?
I would like to remove the glass from this storm door and replace it with a screen for the summer. I cannot find any identification on the door to indicate a serial number or manufacturer. Can you identify the manufacturer or tell me how to determine the manufacturer without serial numbers or identification? The storm door came with our unit. I am in Colorado Springs, Colorado. The unit was built in 1983. I do not know when the storm door was installed or by whom. I have asked the person I purchased the unit from. No info.

Inquire with an aluminium window and door company in your area.  Finding the exact manufacturer for those doors is very difficult.  Sometimes the glass is easy to remove and sometimes it is almost impossible.  If the glass can come out, the local hardware store, ( not big box) sometimes makes screens to a custom size.

the clarity of your picture makes me think of this picture https://a57.foxnews.com/a57.foxnews.com/static.foxnews.com/foxnews.com/content/uploads/2018/09/640/320/1862/1048/bigfoot1_rogerpatterson.jpg?ve=1&tl=1?ve=1&tl=1

Identifying things like this over the Internet is Real Tough. Even those who know what to look for are going to have trouble finding the details.
However: There are people who sell screen panels. If you send them the exact dimensions of the glass panel, including it's frame, they may be able to supply something off the shelf, or custom build it for you. That's probably going to be a lot easier.
(Deliberately not recommending vendors; I have no experience with any of them. Your local glass suppliers or building contractors might be able to make specific recommendations. Heck, my own local glass shop offers custom screens themselves.)
